# Excel VB Workbook_Open() only works manually

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that open another workbook and copies a range of data over. After that it does some data collection and sends an email. The issue I have is that the Workbook_Open() function to autorun this when the workbook is open does not work correctly. If I have the original workbook open and run it from the VB editor all works fine. If however, I let it run automatically it hangs and says the "Select method of the Worksheet class has failed"

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Call send_Mail
End Sub

Private Sub send_Mail()
   Dim Mail As CDO.Message
   Set Mail = New CDO.Message
   
   Dim strFilename As String: strFilename = "S:\Office\Requisition Logs\FY22\FY 2022.xlsx"
   Dim wb2 As Workbook
   Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strFilename)
   Dim vals As Variant

   'Store the value in a variable:
   vals = wb2.Sheets("FY2022 Log").Range("A2:AJ500").Value
   'Close wb2:
   wb2.Close savechanges:=False
   
   Dim wb1 As Workbook
   Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

   'Use the variable to assign a value to the other file/sheet:
   wb1.Sheets("FY2022 Log").Range("A2:AJ500").Value = vals
   wb1.Sheets("FY2022 Log").Select
   
   
   Dim x As Integer
   x = 1
   
   Dim lastRow As Integer
   Dim lastCol As Integer
   Dim startRow As Integer
   Dim numRows As Integer
   startRow = 2
   .............................
```

I do have the Workbook_Open() in the Workbook tab of the ThisWorkbook

Comment: `wb1.Activate` before `wb1.Sheets("FY2022 Log").Select`.

Comment: I get "Method 'Activate' of object '_Workbook' failed." ......but not when I run it manually from VB editor. " I'm not understanding why it works manually and not automatically.

Comment: Is the workbook your personal workbook (personal.xlsb), or saved as an addin (xlam)? Or a regular xlsm?

Comment: file.xlsm is version I saved as

Comment: I ended up changing it up from a Workbook_Open() script to a Public sub in a Module. I then created a standalone VB script to start an Excel.Application, open the file and run the macro. This worked. Not sure why it didn't work the other way. Probably some kind of security settings on the LAN at work.